# Why do Sylow $p$-groups in finite simple group have trivial intersection?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I'm looking for an argument for the fact that two Sylow $p$-subgroups in a finite simple group have trivial intersection.
In the case that the order of the Sylow subgroups is the prime $p$ it is easy, but I don't see how I can prove it in the general case of a prime power.

Comment: You won't be able to prove it because it is not true in general.

Comment: @DerekHolt yes, it is. He is talking about simple groups.

Comment: $\langle (1,2,3),(4,5,6)  \rangle$ and $\langle (1,2,3),(5,6,7) \rangle$ are two Sylow $3$-subgroups of $A_7$ with non-trivial intersection.

Comment: I was mistaken, I conflated "intersection of conjugate subgroups" with "intersection of all conjugate subgroups."

Comment: @DerekHolt and JonathanHebert Thank you!